# VSCode: TypeError item 2 in _argtypes_ passes a union by value, which is unsupported

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I get the exception above. Can anyone help me find the cause. This is my code:

```
import pyttsx3  # pip install pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init() # creating a variable named engine
#engine.say('Hello World...!') #calling that function
#engine.runAndWait() #it is also a pre build funtion used to run and wait till funtion is completed
```

Comment: I just installed pyttsx3 and run the 2 line script and had no error (Python3.8.5)

Answer (score 3):

When I used "`pip install pyttsx3`" to install module `pyttsx3`, I encountered the situation you described:

[image]

I saw in the pip list that the default installed `pyttsx3` is version 2.90, so I installed the 2.71 version of pyttsx3 using "`pip install pyttsx3==2.71`". After debugging the code, I heard the sound: "Hello World!".

The debugging results of the console:

[image]

The Python version I use: Python3.7.6 and Python3.8.3. They can all run the above code.